# running a Perl script on the server after post-receive hook runs on git repo

Tags: git

I have three machines: "devel", "repo", and "server". I need to do some housekeeping on the devel machine before I `git push` the changes to the repo. I call this "preflight". Then, I go to the server, and `git pull` and then I need to do some more housekeeping to prepare everything to update and restart the web app. I call this housekeeping on the server "postflight."

I am able to do the preflight by running a Perl script which actually does the preflight housekeeping, and then does the git add,commit,push dance.

I would like to automated the process on the other end. That is, when the repo receives the update, I would like to run update the server. On a local repo, that is a "server" that also has the repo on it, I can do that via the following `post-receive` hook

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/directory git checkout -f
```

My questions:

1. How can I run a `post-receive` hook (or some other way) to automatically update the directory on the server which happens to be a different machine? and
2. How can I run the postflight Perl script after the server has been updated?

   Update: I have created a `post-checkout` hook on "test." The hook is the Perl script I want executed after "test" receives the updated copy of the code from the "repo." However, the Perl script never runs. I was also tried with the hook renamed to `post-merge` but no joy that way either. How can I ensure that a hook on the client runs when it is updated?

Answer (score 0):

**suppose your next hop is github ; here is trigger should look like**

**Post receive hook code**

```
    #!/bin/bash -x

    GIT_DIR=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $0)) )
    git push  --mirror /home/mvaidya/mirroring_test/backup.git 
    #above URL this should be github
```

Comment: I am not using github anywhere in the above sequence of events. Also, your suggestion, as far as I can understand it, only helps me with the first part of my question. I still need to run a postflight script on the server, perhaps as a post-receive hook on that.